# Maven/Java Issues with Windows Filepath

Tags: java, windows, maven, java-16

New to Java and Maven here. I am having problems successfully running `mvn install` on my Windows setup on **JDK 16**. The process always fails the verification step. The fail-safe folder from Maven shows the following error:

```
Caused by: java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <:> at index 2:  D:\swigwin-4.0.1
```

The process works fine on Mac though. I have already tried changing the encodings, doing a clean install and etc, to no avail.

Any idea how to get around this issue?

Comment: Looks like you're using some Unix tech in Windows and it doesn't like the `:` in a file name (invalid in Unix as it's the path separator). You might need to get rid of drive letters.

Comment: The path above is based on some dependencies innate to the Java.nio package I think. Not sure what I can do about that.

Comment: I very much doubt it. Nio is part of the jre and platform-independent. I'm guessing what's happening is the nio classes are telling you that you have a character (`:`) that's invalid as part of a Unix file name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was using cmd.exe as the terminal in IntelliJ, switching to a proper unix based terminal like Git Bash solved the issue for me. The comment about was right.